# Trying to write out a program

Tags: c#

Ok for my program I am trying to get it so that when I have a Key press on my program and  say I Press L and it moves in the 4x4 2d array and I get to pit which I designated as P on the array I want it to know it hit the P and print out you have a hit a Pit or if I reach where it has G on the array I want it to print out you have found gold. Any help is appreciated.

```
using System;

namespace DragonCave
{
    public struct DragonPlayer
    {
        public int X, Y;
        public string CurrentMove;
    }

    public class DragonGameboard
    {
        public string[,] GameboardArray;
        public DragonPlayer Player;
        private Random r;

        public DragonGameboard(){
            GameboardArray = new string[4,4];
            Player.CurrentMove = "";
            r = new Random();
            Player.X = r.Next(0, 4);
        Player.Y = r.Next(0, 4);
        GenerateRandomBoard();
    }

    private void GenerateRandomBoard()
    {
       //Put a dot in every spot
        int row;
        int col;
        for (row = 0; row < 4; row++)
        {
            for (col = 0; col < 4; col++)
            {
                Console.Write(GameboardArray[row, col] = ".");
            }
            //Console.WriteLine();
        }

        //Randomly Places the entrance, dragon, pit and gold.

        GameboardArray[r.Next(0,4), r.Next(0, 4)] = "E";
        GameboardArray[r.Next(0,4), r.Next(0,4)] = "D";
        GameboardArray[r.Next(0, 4), r.Next(0, 4)] = "P";
        GameboardArray[r.Next(0, 4), r.Next(0, 4)] = "P";
        GameboardArray[r.Next(0, 4), r.Next(0, 4)] = "P";
        GameboardArray[r.Next(0, 4), r.Next(0, 4)] = "G";
    }

    public void PrintBoard()
    {
        int row;
        int col;
        for (row = 0; row < 4; row++)
        {
            for (col = 0; col < 4; col++)
            {
                Console.Write(GameboardArray[row, col] + "\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Cheat you are in"  + Player.X + "," + Player.Y);

        //fill with room numbers

    }

    public  void ProcessMove(string move)
    {
        switch (move)
        {
            case "F":
                Console.WriteLine("You chose forward");
                break;
            case "L":
                Player.X--;
                Player.Y--;
                //Console.WriteLine("You chose Left");
                Console.WriteLine("A Breeze is in the air");
                break;
            case "R":
                Player.X++;
                Player.Y++;
                if (GameboardArray)
                Console.WriteLine("You chose Right");
                break;
            case "G":
                Console.WriteLine("You chose Grab gold");
                break;
            case "S":
                Console.WriteLine("You chose Shoot arrow");
                break;
            case "C":
                Console.WriteLine("You chose Climb");
                break;
            case "Q":
                Console.WriteLine("You chose Quit");
                break;
            case "X":
                Console.WriteLine("You chose Cheat");
                PrintBoard();
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid move!!!!!!!!!!1");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be beneficial to anyone trying to answer your question if you explained what is happening and why it's not what you desire. Clearly state your goal and the current behavior and ask a question. Once you do that, I am certain more people will be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Just check what the string is at GameboardArray[player.x, player.y].

```
public void ProcessTileEvent()
{
    if( Player.X >= 0 && Player.X < 4 && Player.Y >= 0 && Player.Y < 4  )
    {
        switch( GameboardArray[Player.X, Player.Y] )
        {
            case "G":
            Console.WriteLine( "You found gold!" );
            break;
            case "P":
            Console.WriteLine( "You fell in a pit!" );
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You'd probably want to do this every time the player moves.

Comment: So lets say I start off at 2,1 in the array and I want to move to 2,2 in the array and I run into a pit which I designate as P would that little snip of code work for the program?

Comment: Well, no, you couldn't just copy and paste it in. However, that's exactly what you'll need to do. 

You have an array of strings, right, and the player moves along that array. You want to check what's under the player, so it makes sense that the string you're after is at the player's position. 

If you're at 2,1 and you move up to 2,2, THEN you check what string is at 2,2 in the array, you'll be able perform an action based on what the string is.